# Hibernate Criteria way to address in with multiple columns

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

Would like to address the below query with Hibernate criteria way,

```
select * from A where (type, Version) in (select type, max(Version) from A group by type)
```

only looking at hibernate criteria way.
suggestion please.

Comment: tried with CriteriaBuilder.in but it is not allowing more than once to provide multiple columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can reformulate this with an exists subquery which you can model with the JPA Criteria API. Something like the following:

```
select * from A a where exists (select 1 from A sub group by sub.type having a.type = sub.type and a.version = max(sub.version))
```